# Rules for incrementing patch number in semver

Tags: api, versioning, semantic-versioning

According to [semver](http://semver.org/)

> "PATCH version when you make backwards-compatible bug fixes."

and

> "A bug fix is defined as an internal change that fixes incorrect behavior."

With this in mind lets say I have a variable that can be called, like a color. And for some reason I need to change the color value.

```
v1.0.0
$color: #FFF;

v1.0.1
$color: #F0F0F0;
```

Now this is a variable that is defined in the API as something users can call. I haven't changed the actual variable that is called, only the value it returns. To do this I have to make a change to my code, on an API element, and I must merge this code into the production branch.  But does something like this truly warrant incrementing the patch version number of your API?

Comment: Are you making a whole new release just for this change? The change should be recorded in the version control system but does it really need to be distributed and released with just that? If so, you have your answer

Comment: @bnjmn what if this is the only change I need to make for weeks? Are users suppose to wait for the update?

Comment: You're changing white to grey and your users can't wait a few weeks for that update unless something major comes along? Mate, you seriously need to get some new users! That's less than a minor fix that can wait...

Comment: @PeteR the color is just an example in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The point of <strike>semantic</strike> versioning is to manage dependencies of software systems. Semantic versioning provides an organized specification to standardize this process in order to reliably track the state of these systems. As the specification states,

> Once a versioned package has been released, the contents of that version MUST NOT be modified. Any modifications MUST be released as a new version.

If your changes affect the behaviour of your api (inputs or outputs) and require a release to be made then that release should be pegged to an appropriate version number. This will allow the users of the package to depend on your package with confidence. Each version will behave as expected; there should be no ambiguity.

---

As an example, let's say you make the change and release it but don't increment the patch number. You could potentially have two users who think they are using the same code but get different values when calling the `$color` api depending on when they acquired `v1.0.0`.

It's worth noting that there are different ways to approach getting this change to users depending on how you release your package. I can think of two possible cases:

- If the package source is public, in early development of the package a quick change could be pushed to a development branch in which users could acquire changes at their own risk.
- Alternatively, if the package is not open source, a pre-release could be made by appending an identifier to the version (see items 9 & 10 in the spec).

These are just a couple options. There may be others depending on your specific situation.

#### TL;DR Answer

Most importantly is that once `v1.0.0` has been released, `v1.0.0` should always behave the same way. Regardless of how trivial these changes may be they are still changes. This goes for all versions, `X.Y.Z`.

Comment: Secondary: what about a change to the API documentation like the README.md, should semver be incremented for these types of changes as well?

Comment: @aaronmallen If it's just a change that you're committing to your repository, then no. However, if you are packaging those changes (whatever "packaging" means for your project), you MUST increment the version number (see item 3 in the spec).

Comment: @deadly so the version number isn't directly related to the source code itself (i.e. the repo) but the package only?

Comment: @aaronmallen Exactly. You only need to decide on a version number when you're making a release.